# Is it possible to construct an adjacency matrix for a graph without storing indexes of nodes

Tags: c, file, indexing, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have managed to implement the solution with storing an index of each node, but is it possible to it without the indexes? My assignment is to implement a bloxrolz game, sort of. In the example I'm about to show you, I am out of ideas how to write code for checking if two nodes are adjacent to one another.

[image]

This is just a random field for the game. When reading from a file, I store every charachter here in a linked list, with a x,y coordinate and ID(if the char is not '-'). Only those that are not "-" are to be stored in a adjacency matrix since they represent the playground and "-" are nodes that could be changed to "-".

I have successfully implemented a solution in a way that I'm not sure if its legitimate or not. Can you help me figure out how to do this without the indexes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adjacency matrix is by definition a binary matrix without any indices.You might want to clarify your question by showing some code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You don'y understand me. I know what an adj. matrix is. I need to create an adjacency matrix without the information about the coordinates of nodes in a graph.

Comment: What do you mean by "indexes of nodes"? Please show some code to illustrate.

Comment: "... that I'm not sure if its legitimate or not." If it works then it is legitimate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice look at he picture above

Comment: No code in pictures!!

Comment: @remax Please post your code example as text. Also be sure to create a [mcve] so that we can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

An adjacency matrix is by definition a square matrix where each node is represented by a row and a column. If the entry at row *i* and column *j* is `1` (or some value you pick), then those two nodes are connected in the graph. Therefore, **you need some way to map rows and columns to nodes** and vice versa. Putting the nodes in a list and using each node's index in the list is one way to do that, but it's not the only way. You could give each node an ID number and, as long as each node's ID is unique and within the bounds of the matrix, you can use that. You could store a pointer to the corresponding node at the beginning or end of each row and column. In short, any method that lets you find the entries in the matrix for a given pair of nodes is sufficient.

That said, because you're talking about ordered lists of rows and columns, any method you pick will be similar to putting the nodes in a list and using the index of a node in the list. Think hard about what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Note that with the appropriate data structure for your "matrix", you can use `(x, y)` pairs as the "node labels" `i` and `j`.